# Why is the timestamp passed to requestAnimationFrame in Chrome sometimes in the past?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, rendering

Chrome sometimes passes a timestamp into the `requestAnimationFrame` ("`rAF`") callback that is **before** the time `rAF` is called. How is that possible?

My test case: I first get a timestamp `t0` using `performance.now()`, then request an animation frame, and finally compare the timestamp `t1` passed to the callback to `t0`: https://jsfiddle.net/cy45gdan/3/

How does it make sense for `t1` to happen before `t0`? Is Chrome calling my callback for an ongoing frame and passes the time that frame started?

Firefox and Safari seem to only pass timestamps into the `rAF` callbacks that are after the time `rAF` is called.

Answer (score 0):

The `DOMHighResTimeStamp` is made **onload**, not when `requestAnimationFrame` is called.

Using your code (nicely done, by the way), I managed to get two (-) numbers in Firefox out of a plethora of tries, while on Chrome I got mostly negative numbers with only a few positive ones.

That means that sometimes the browsers run code before they make the timestamp onload, which would result in a positive number. I have no idea what the root cause of the fluctuation is, so I won't even speculate.